# Windows 10 - Spacing/Gap Between Combined Windows in taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar

I have a problem where after my windows are stacked on top of each other with the option "Always, hide labels" for the setting "Combine taskbar button" under Taskbar, there is a huge gap between each window, stretching the preview out.

[image: How taskbar looks right now]

This is a problem with everything as long as they have multiple windows and are stacked on top of each other. The gap is also unclickable (nothing happens) even though it is still a preview window.

How can I revert it back before this where the gap isn't there? I created a new local account to test if the problem also exists, but the gap isn't there, so I'm guessing it's a local account issue.

Edit: I think this happened after I changed the display scaling for my monitor.

Answer (score 0):

LET IT BE KNOWN.

Download Winaero Tweaker, search for "taskbar thumbnail", spam click "Reset this page to defaults" because somehow multiple clicks are necessary, and problem is fixed. The gap is gone.

Thank the world. I can finally get some sleep.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).